# ffmpeg: crop video into two grayscale sub-videos; guarantee monotonical frames; and get timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

### The need

Hello, I need to **extract two regions of a .h264 video file via the `crop`** filter into two files. The output videos need to be **monochrome and extension .mp4**. The encoding (or format?) should guarantee that **video frames are organized monotonically**. Finally, I need to get **the timestamps** for both files (which I'd bet are the same timestamps that I would get from the input file, see below).

In the end I will be happy to do everything in one command via an elegant one liner (via a complex filter I guess), but I start doing it in multiple steps to break it down in simpler problems.

In this path I get into many difficulties and despite having searched in many places I don't seem to find solutions that work. Unfortunately I'm no expert of ffmpeg or video conversion, so the more I search, the more details I discover, the less I solve problems.

Below you find some of my attempts to work with the following options:

- `-filter:v "crop=400:ih:260:0,format=gray"` to do the crop and the monochrome conversion
- `-vf showinfo` possibly combined with `-vsync 0` or `-copyts` to get the timestamps via stderr redirection `&> filename`
- `-c:v mjpeg` to force monotony of frames (are there other ways?)

#### 1. cropping each region and obtaining monochrome videos

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i inVideo.h264 -filter:v "crop=400:ih:260:0,format=gray" outL.mp4
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i inVideo.h264 -filter:v "crop=400:ih:1280:0,format=gray" outR.mp4
```

The issue here is that in the output files **the frames are not organized monotonically** (I don't understand why; how come would that make sense in any video format? I can't say if that comes from the input file).

**EDIT**. Maybe it is not *frames*, but *packets*, as returned by `av .demux()` method that are not monotonic (see below "instructions to reproduce...")

I have got the advice to do a `ffmpeg -i outL.mp4 outL.mjpeg` after, but this produces two videos that look very pixellated (at least playing them with ffplay) despite being surprisingly 4x bigger than the input. **Needless to say, I need both monotonic frames and lossless conversion.**

**EDIT**. I acknowledge the advice to specify `-q:v 1`; this fixes the pixellation effect but produces a file even bigger, ~12x in size. Is it  necessary? (see below "instructions to reproduce...")

#### 2. getting the timestamps

I found [this piece of advice](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/how-to-decode-the-pts-timestamps-and-extract-the-video-frames), but I don't want to generate hundreds of image files, so I tried the following:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i outL.mp4 -vf showinfo -vsync 0 &>tsL.txt
$ ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i outR.mp4 -vf showinfo -vsync 0 &>tsR.txt
```

The issue here is that I don't get any output because ffmpeg claims it needs an output file.

The need to produce an output file, and the doubt that the timestamps could be lost in the previous conversions, leads me back to making a first attempt of a one liner, where I am testing also the `-copyts` option, and the forcing the encoding with `-c:v mjpeg` option as per the advice mentioned above (don't know if in the right position though)

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i testTex2.h264 -copyts -filter:v "crop=400:ih:1280:0,format=gray" -vf showinfo -c:v mjpeg eyeL.mp4 &>tsL.txt
```

This does not work because surprisingly the output .mp4 I get is the same as the input. If instead I put the `-vf showinfo` option just before the stderr redirection, I get no redirected output

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i testTex2.h264 -copyts -filter:v "crop=400:ih:260:0,format=gray" -c:v mjpeg outR.mp4 -vf showinfo dummy.mp4 &>tsR.txt
```

In this case I get the desired timestamps output (too much: I will need some solution to grab only the pts and pts_time data out of it) but I have to produce a big dummy file. The worst thing is anyway, that **the mjpeg encoding produces a low resolution very pixellated video again**

I admit that the logic how to place the options and the output files on the command line is obscure to me. Possible combinations are many, and the more options I try the more complicated it gets, and I am not getting much closer to the solution.

### 3. [EDIT] instructions how to reproduce this

- get a .h264 video
- turn it into .mp by ffmpeg command `$ ffmpeg -i inVideo.h264 out.mp4`
- run the following python cell in a jupyter-notebook
- see that the packets timestamps have diffs greater and less than zero

```
%matplotlib inline
import av
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

fname, ext="outL.direct", "mp4"

cont=av.open(f"{fname}.{ext}")
pk_pts=np.array([p.pts for p in cont.demux(video=0) if p.pts is not None])

cont=av.open(f"{fname}.{ext}")
fm_pts=np.array([f.pts for f in cont.decode(video=0) if f.pts is not None])

print(pk_pts.shape,fm_pts.shape)

mpl.subplot(211)
mpl.plot(np.diff(pk_pts))

mpl.subplot(212)
mpl.plot(np.diff(fm_pts))
```

- finally create also the mjpeg encoded files in various ways, and check packets monotony with the same script (see also file size)

```
$ ffmpeg -i inVideo.h264 out.mjpeg
$ ffmpeg -i inVideo.h264 -c:v mjpeg out.c_mjpeg.mp4
$ ffmpeg -i inVideo.h264 -c:v mjpeg -q:v 1 out.c_mjpeg_q1.mp4
```

### Finally, the question

What is a working way / the right way to do it?

Any hints, even about single steps and how to rightly combine them will be appreciated. Also, I am not limited tio the command line, and I would be able to try some more programmatic solution in python (jupyter notebook) instead of the command line if someone points me in that direction.

Comment: a)`.h264` files have no timestamps. b) *the frames are not organized monotonically* --> what does this mean and how are you detecting it?  c)The `mjpeg` encoder defaults to 200 kbps. Add `-q:v 1`

Comment: @Gyan, b) is a conclusion driven by someone else, not me, about the .mp4 files made with the crop command. I might have misunderstood. A) and c) good to know. I'll work on them

Comment: Until you clear up (b), it's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @Gyan, here you go. This is the original claim about the issue (so look: the *monotonical* adjectve was mine): *I noticed a playback issue due to the encoding of the video. The program expects the video packets to be decoded **in the same order** as they are presented. This is not the case for all h264 videos. I recommend converting your input videos to mjpeg (ffmpeg -i eye0.mp4 eye0.mjpeg) as this format guarantees this constraint*

Comment: @Gyan, pls find some more answers in the EDITs